# Blank filename in HTML5 download Attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Here, I am trying to download CSV file but i am getting file without any file extension.

I am using http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/KPEGU/ to export data in CSV format.

Even if you run above example it is downloading file which do not have any file extension.

Here I have listed my code.

```
var csvString = response;
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href     = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csvString);
a.target   = '_blank';
a.download = 'Report.csv';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

Comment: None of that code is Jquery...

Comment: Looks like Chrome bug. Works ok under FF29.

Comment: ...works on Opera 12 too